# Using Django as API gateway & authorizations service in Microservice

Tags: python, django, microservices, api-gateway

I wanted to create a Microservice that will use Django as its API Gateway for the GraphQL.

This is the desired output of my service architecture.

[image]

Can some one please explain to me how to reach to this end, or provide a meaningful resources to create a microservice with Django.

Comment: I mean what's the problem here? Are you asking us to build the whole django application? Look here https://www.djangoproject.com/ .

Comment: The problem is making Django to run as API gateway that will take all sub-graphs from other sub-services and make the as one GraphQL super-graph, also it will redirect all request to specific services.

Comment: So. Have you written any code yet? If so, and if you face any problems doing so, you can post here those problems. Look here https://www.djangoproject.com/   This contain lot of information.